# Burger menu doesn't work in iOS webview

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone, webview

I have been struggling with my website burger menu. In fact, I'm actually trying to implement [this website](https://www.mercato-emploi.com) into an android and an iOS webview. This website, in responsive mode, has a burger menu, supposed to block the scroll and show a block with different link.

I've been trying to debug my iOS version, cause the menu appears, but click on a link isn't well detected. At sometimes, you have to make long click and it works, sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes it even handles the click on background content. Actually, I don't understand what the matter is. Does anybody have an idea of what it's due to?

Comment: Hi try to add in your media queries a z-index superior to test if isn't a layer or something invisible "overflow hidden" for example are front the zone links.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but I've actually already try this trick. No layer visible or with a superior z-index.. Any other idea?